# Force client to use newest js files from vue router lazy loading

Tags: javascript, vue.js, lazy-loading, laravel-mix, code-splitting

i am building vue js spa project with laravel and because of that i am using laravel mix (version 5.0.9) and i am also adding vue route lazy load to make my project overall more snappier and faster.

the problem is whenever i update my project and upload it to the server, and user/client who using my project will getting error since my apps not loading the newest page for those route but using the old cache from the client browser which make the apps not working like it supposed to be because of the code splitting from lazy load.

is there anyway to tell the client to automatically fetch the newest whenever i upload newest version of my app?

my configuration:

1. Laravel 5.6
2. Vue 2.6.10
3. laravel mix 5.0.9

Comment: You can try to use .version() in your mix file, see here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix#versioning-and-cache-busting

Comment: I’m not familiar with the stack you use, cannot provide concrete solution. However cache validity problem in general is covered in this [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching) which I recommend you to read. The "Revved resources" section describes the popular technique frontend developers use these days.